# Heroku WHERE error from Postgres Datatype mismatch in my Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

> PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer 
>   LINE 1: SELECT "timecards".* FROM "timecards"  WHERE (user_id)  ORDE...

This in in my controller:

```
def index

 @users = User.find(:all)   
 @timecards = Timecard.find(:all, :conditions => "user_id", :order => "checkin_time ASC")

 @worklogs = Timecard.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id=>current_user}, :order => "checkin_time ASC")
 @jobs = Job.find(:all, :conditions =>"id") 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better would be

`Timecard.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(:checkin_time)`

Comment: But that would leave `@timecards` and `@worklogs` holding the same stuff, no? This was my initial thought but the duplicates left me a bit confused about the real intent.

Comment: Hm, I guess I'd be confused about what the difference between `@timecards` and `@worklogs` is. What is the intent/use of each variable? Do you need both?

Comment: timecards is all users work history sorted by id; worklogs is only showing current users work history

Answer (score 2):

The problem is right here:

```
@timecards = Timecard.find(:all, :conditions => "user_id", :order => "checkin_time ASC")
# ----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

If you give it a String in the `:conditions` then that String goes straight into the SQL and

```
where (user_id)
```

doesn't make any sense to PostgreSQL because `user_id` is an integer column. You're going to have the same problem with `Job.find(:all, :conditions => "id")`. I have no idea what either of those `:conditions` should be though.

I also suspect that you're developing on top of SQLite since you (presumably) didn't find this problem in your development or testing environments. If you're deploying on top of PostgreSQL then you really should develop and test on top of PostgreSQL. You should always develop, test, and deploy using the same stack, there's no such thing as database portability (unless you do it yourself) and no ORM will protect you from database differences.

I'd also recommend that you move away from the old Rails2-style `find(:all, ...)` stuff in favor of a more modern `.where(...).where(...).order(...)` approach.

Comment: conditions for timecards is to find all work history for all users by user id; conditions for worklogs is to find all work history for the current user

Comment: And what did you expect `:conditions => "user_id"` to do? Did you get the results you were looking for in your development environment?

Comment: yes I did; however, I am using sqlite3 in development and postgres in deployment for heroku. The user id condition helps me sort all the timecards to display under each associated user. If you just retrieve all, I have to display the user name everytime I display a timecard log. Much easier to just have the name listed once and all his logs together.

Comment: i wish i could accept your answer also but it only allows me to choose one. It won't let me give you props either. thanks for your help